# How to diff between a git and svn repos

Tags: git, svn, repository, diff

I recently forked a project in github and made a clone on my disk. I was working on this same project which I had on SVN before I find that someone else also worked on it. I don't have write access on SVN repo. I only have a changed copy on my disk. Now I have a clone of my own git and a SVN clone.

I want to apply my changes in SVN copy to my git clone. Do you know any tool for Windows which can help? I know [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) does something similar but I am not sure if it would work with a local copy of SVN.

Edit: Actually I want to merge two repos.
Edit 2: A very important ability which I am looking for is to set a done flag for each file I am finished merging.

Comment: A "local SVN copy" is just a working directory (since SVN is a centralised system) you can use any diffing tool to compare your two working areas - for example WinDIFF or probably even Visual Studio Code with a plugin of some sort.

Comment: I used WinMerge actually but it was a bit hard to work with as it didn't display folder structures when showing the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best way or not but it is a feasible solution. What I did was to first create a SVN repo from my working copy, then converted it to a git repo. Then I fetched it from the original git repo and merged. This way we can easily see the conflicting files and resolve them.